# Function pointers and functors

Tags: c++, functor

Are function pointers functors ? Is there a virtual functor in use that helps sibling functors compile silently ?

Comment: C++11 introduces the notion of a "callable type", which means (loosely) that some construction like `INVOKE(yourthing, a, b, c)`, which expands to `yourthing(a,b,c)`, has to make sense; that encompasses both function pointers and functors and is probably a good way to think generically.

Comment: Sorry, I just intermixed the terms, because the outcome looks more interesting I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least as the term is normally used in C++ (Warning: it's used *entirely* differently relative to other languages such as Haskell), a functor is a class (or an instance of a class) that overloads `operator()` so it can be invoked like a function.

Since they use the same syntax, a template can be written to accept either a pointer to a function *or* an instance of a functor interchangeably. Not all algorithms will do so however -- some expect (for example) that you supply something with `typedef`s for things like `argument_type` and `result_type`. The standard library provides a couple of classes (`unary_function` and `binary_function`) to use as base classes for your functors to supply these. You can supply them on your own if you prefer -- these base classes are purely for convenience (and some people don't find them particularly convenient).

Comment: +1, but add that a function pointer is not *actually* a functor, even though it can be used with templates that expect one.

Comment: I've always heard and gone by the definition that a functor is anything that can be called, either a function object or an actual function.  And the thing you're calling a functor is specifically a function object.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't upvote, but already mark your reply as an accepted answer, it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

A function pointer is the address of a real function. A functor is a class for which the `operator()` has been overloaded; instances of these classes can be passed around and called with the same syntax as a function. So no, function pointers are not functors.

I don't know what "virtual functors" or "sibling functors" are, so I can't answer your second question.

Comment: Thank you for your explanition